# Add JavaScript to single post

Tags: javascript

I want to add small javascript program in wordpress post, please let me know how to add / execute in WP Post ?

### EDIT

Yes I tried, but no luck.

First I added HTML Code & JavaScript in Post Text Editor, No Luck,
Then I created Separate JS file & posted only HTML code & called js file using `<Script src=<Path of the JS File>>` - No Luck.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to create a shortcode exclusively for that script. Even thought it's not an elegant solution, it works. In your functions file (functions.php) of your theme add:

```
function custom_script_shortcode(){
    $code = '<script>';
    $code .= 'var foo = "bar";'
    $code .= '</script>';
    return $code;
}
add_shortcode("custom_script_shortcode", "custom_script");
```

And in your post editor then add the shortcode:

```
[custom_script]
```

Just be careful when you assign your JavaScript to the variable $code so you don't close the string with " or '

Answer (score 0):

You can add your script on header or footer normally with .
Or you can hooked your script on function.php like this way:

```
function theme_name_scripts() {
wp_enqueue_style( 'style-name', get_stylesheet_uri() );
wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/example.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts' );
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is for all the posts, an external script is always a better idea, linked with `wp_enqueue_script()` (see [this article](http://www.sitepoint.com/including-javascript-in-plugins-or-themes/) for more information).

If you only want to add a code to a single post, simply write it in the editor (into a `script` tag, in the "Text" tab).

Comment: Hi, just want to add in a single post, i tried in the text editor HTML & JS, but its not executing.

Comment: When you save your post (save the draft or publish the article), is the `script` tag still here? If it disappears, that means you don't have the rights to do that, you must be at least an editor.

Answer (score 0):

If you go in and edit the post, and click the "Text" tab, and enter your code in `<script>` tags:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
console.log("gosh");
</script>
```

and update the post, the content should save as

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
console.log("gosh");
// ]]></script>
```

which should execute when the post is viewed.